# Programming a color by numbers type interface

Tags: java, python, processing

I am a Fine Arts major trying to program an applet that viewers can use when they come to the gallery for my senior show.
I am trying to program a color by numbers type paint/fill program based on images I create for my thesis.

I was thinking that there would be a couple of images which the user gets to select in the beginning, and then they pick a color, and then select a shape on the screen, click, and my image gets colored with their color.
When completed, they could print out their reproduction of my work.

I think I know how to do it, the part I think I would have the hardest part with is breaking the template image into fill() able shapes.  Is there is a way to end fills when a pixel goes from white to black(the stroke of the image)?

I know some python, and am taking an intro comp-sci class which works in processing, a simplified java.

Thanks so much!

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill

Answer (score 1):

You can use floodfill in python with opencv.

There is an example of floodfill in here that you can "play"

https://code.ros.org/trac/opencv/browser/trunk/opencv/samples/python2/floodfill.py?rev=6080

ps. you need to install opencv and numpy